# Visual Studio Crash on creating new Class

Tags: nanoframework

Visual Studio 2019 16.6.5 frequently crashes when creating a new class/interface or renaming an existing class/interface. This seems to be related to the nanoframework extension as it never happens when I am developing Windows applications.

Andy

Comment: Also crashed when I clicked on manage nuget packages :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this on projects under Git version control. The nanoFramework extension is not called during the rename process which is exclusively handled by VS. So it's unlikely that this is related with our extension.